# Django serializing separate variables into json

Tags: python, objective-c, json, django

I have min max variables that are a result of query on model

```
args.aggregate(Min('price'))
args.aggregate(Max('price'))
```

returning the serialized data like this

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps([{"maxPrice":args.aggregate(Max('price')),
                "minPrice":args.aggregate(Min('price'))}]), content_type ='application/json')
```

the result looks like this:

```
minPrice =     {
    "price__min" = 110;
};
maxPrice =     {
    "price__max" = 36000;
};
```

and extracting the data looks like this

```
...
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
          NSDictionary *elements = responseObject;
          int minPrice = elements[0][@"minPrice"][@"price__min"];
      }
```

**The Question:** how to change the django/python code in order for the objective-c code to look like this: `int minPrice = elements[@"minPrice"];`

Answer (score 1):

```
data = args.aggregate(minPrice=Min('price'), maxPrice=Max('price'))
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

data variable is a dictionary with "minPrice" and "maxPrice" keys.

Answer (score 0):

Dump to JSON a dictionary instead of a list:

```
values = args.aggregate(Min('price'), Max('price'))

return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'maxPrice': values['price__max'], 
                                'minPrice': values['price__min']}),
                    content_type ='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like this to rearrange the json dump:

```
data = {'maxPrice': args.aggregate(Max('price'))['price__max'],
        'minPrice': args.aggregate(Min('price'))['price__min']}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type ='application/json')
```

That should give you a json dict of that form `'{"maxPrice": xxx, "minPrice": yyy}'`.